# c++ calling a template function defined in separate header and cpp files

Tags: c++

I have a simple template function,

A.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
pair<T, T> GetMatchedBin(T, vector<pair<T, T> >);
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

template<class T>
pair<T, T> GetMatchedBin(T val, vector<pair<T, T> > &bins)
{
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<bins.size(); i++){
        if(val >= bins[i].first && val < bins[i].second)
            return bins[i];
    }
    return pair<T, T>();
}
```

which I call via,

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "A.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<pair<int, int> > bins;
    bins.push_back(pair<int, int>(0, 1));
    bins.push_back(pair<int, int>(1, 2));
    bins.push_back(pair<int, int>(2, 3));
    bins.push_back(pair<int, int>(3, 4));

    pair<int, int> matched_bin = GetMatchedBin(3, bins);

    cout << matched_bin.first << ", " << matched_bin.second << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However when I try to compile this I get the error,

```
make
g++ -o temp temp.cpp A.o
/tmp/dvoong/ccoSJ4eF.o: In function `main':
temp.cpp:(.text+0x12a): undefined reference to `std::pair<int, int> GetMatchedBin<int>(int, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [temp] Error 1
```

The odd thing is that if I do this all in one file rather than dividing into header and .cpp files then it works...

Any idea what is causing this?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/951890

Answer (score 4):

The compiler needs the full definition of the template at compile time. Thus, the definition of the template function needs to be in the header. (unless you specialize, that has to be in a c++ file or inlined)

Comment: thanks, your answer just reminded me I've already had this problem once before